# Connecting to Azure SSAS Model from Windows 7 / Excel 2013

Tags: sql-server, excel, azure, ssas, azure-analysis-services

Our team have built a model on Azure's SSAS platform. We have no problem connecting to it from Windows 10, but we cannot get Excel to connect for our Windows 7 users. (Excel 2013)

I followed the steps [described here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/analysis-services/instances/data-providers-used-for-analysis-services-connections#bkmk_downloadsite) to get the latest data drivers, but still had no luck after installation.

Can anyone provide insight or steps to connect?

Our only proposed solution for the moment is to upgrade the users to Windows 10. But this will take quite a bit of time and bureaucracy as we're dealing with a large enterprise IT setup.

Comment: Normally I would ask for an error message or further explanation of "no luck", but there is probably no solution

Answer (score 0):

If you have installed the latest OLEDB provider from the link you mentioned then I would follow these instructions to create an [ODC](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/analysis-services/analysis-services-odc?) file.